# How to wait for request and user input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

Let's say when a component loads I make an async request. That component also has a submit button that the user can press which triggers a function that relies on the result of that original request. How do I delay executing the triggered function until the async request is finished?

If that doesn't make sense let me give an example. `MyComponent` makes an async request `getRandomColor()` on `mounted`. `MyComponent`'s template has `<button @click="handleClick">`. `handleClick` calls some function `saveColor()`. How do I make sure that `saveColor()` is not called until my async `getRandomColor()` is finished?

I'm currently using Vue.js but I think this question applies to all of javascript.

Comment: disable the submit button until the asycn request completes ... i.e. in the success handler of the async function, enable the submit button (which you should set as disabled by default)

Comment: a detailed solution of @Bravo is to define a data variable with initial value of false and bind this variable to disabled attribute of your button and on response of your async request change the value of the variable to true. if you need more detail or implementation let me know

Comment: @Dallin - You can achieve this by adding :disabled attribute in your button element. The value of :disabled will be based on the response. i.e. If response will be there then enabled it otherwise disabled. I added a code snippet in the answer for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `:disabled` attribute in your button element. The value of `:disabled` will be based on the response. i.e. If response will be there then enabled it otherwise disabled.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        buttonText: 'Call Me!',
      apiResponse: [],
      isDisabled: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveColor() {
        console.log('saveColor method call');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(response => {
      this.apiResponse = response.data; // Here we are getting proper response. hence, button is getting enabled.
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn('API error');
        });
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="saveColor()" :disabled="!apiResponse.length">{{ buttonText }}</button>
</div>
```

Adding below snippet as per the comment added by the author of the post.

> What if I didn't want to use the disabled button? Is there a way to make the button handler wait for the request to finish before it continues execution?

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        buttonText: 'Call Me!',
      apiResponse: [],
      isDisabled: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveColor() {
        console.log('saveColor method call');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(response => {
      this.apiResponse = response.data; // Here we are getting proper response. hence, button is getting enabled.
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn('API error');
        });
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click.prevent="apiResponse.length ? saveColor() : {}">{{ buttonText }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome reply. But I have a follow up question. What if I didn't want to use the disabled button? Is there a way to make the button handler wait for the request to finish before it continues execution?

Comment: @DallinDavis Yes we can achieve that. I added one more code snippet as per the requirement. Please check and let me know if that works for you!